# modular programming in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, content-management-system, web-parts

I don't know whether usage of the term 'modular programming' as the topic title is correct or not. 
I'm developing a website application which consist of different parts such as:

- Registering information
- Editing information
- Changing user password and so on.

This software will be uploaded on different servers.
This software should have a part using which the Administrator of software can physically remove the other mentioned above parts or add them again.
If I wanna explain more, Administrator can check or uncheck the check boxes and specify which parts to physically remove or copy.

What can I do? I have heard about modular programming in CMSes like Drupal, Joomla in which a user can install or uninstall modules.

Can I remove my ASPX files in runtime?

Comment: It seems that you want to use something like cms. There are some cms based on Asp.net, also there is the concept 'web part' which exists in Asp.net and Sharepoint.

Comment: I don't want to use a cms but I want to write something like it with ASP.net c#, what is your idea about it's implementation?

Comment: You can try to use web parts (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0s9t4ck.aspx), they can be modified by administrator in a browser. The most probably that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648752.aspx.
It says "They support XCopy deployment of independently developed modules."

But for the kind of modules you have mentioned I suggest to implement it as normal web site and deploy only ASPX files you want to give access.
The DLL of website will have code for all the ASPX but you can deploy selected ASPX file and it is perfectly fine.

In addition to this you need to set navigation accordingly so that this removed files should not appear in navigation, for that you can use SiteMapDataSource.

Find example at http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_navigation.asp.

This sitemap is xml so it is easy to generate it dynamically based on same criteria of deploying selective ASPX files.